# Child node is bigger than parent but parent does expand content to fit child size

Tags: html, css, padding

I have a `<th>` element which contains an `<a>` element.

The `<a>` element:

- is not absolute,
- is not floated out
- dimensions are not set
- have padding on each side

---

The `<th>` element:

- is not relative,
- not floated out
- dimensions are not set
- has `padding: 0;`

So, based on the images provided, why the `<th>` does not expand to fit **height** of the child `<a>`?

I've tried `height: fit-content;` but nothing.

The first image shows boundaries of the `<th>` node.
[image]

---

The second image shows boundaries of the `<a>` node.

You can clearly see that it has padding that increase its dimensions making it bigger than parent.
But why it does not expand parent dimensions?
[image]

Comment: This could be caused by the `a`s `display` property. by default, `a` tags are `display: inline`.
Try setting it to `block` and see if it then has an effect on the parent `th`

Comment: Thank you @whitespace for your answer, but it has already been converted to a block element when having that problem.

Comment: Can you provide a reproduction? maybe on codesendbox or as a code snippet?